# How to change tensor shape in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose I have, in Tensorflow, a tensor of shape `[3,4,4]`, which is not known explicitly.  How can I change its shape to `[3,4,4,1]`?
I tried to use reshape function but because I do not explicitly know the tensor shape, it cannot be used directly.

Answer (score 1):

Given t of shape `[3,4,4]`, it can be reshape to `[3,4,4, 1]`

```
tf.reshape(t, [3,4,4, 1]) # by explicitly specifying the shape
tf.expandims(t, 3) # implicitly we expand the dimension 3 with size 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use tf.expand_dims(t, -1) to add 1 to the end of the shape

I.e.

```
t.shape : [3, 4, 4]
tf.expand_dims(t, -1).shape : [3, 4, 4, 1]
```